# Query for unconventional people names in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to search for the people in a table (10 mil records +) with an unusual names with special characters such as some following samples:

```
Subject_Name (lastname, firstname):
*S-luis-Hernandez, Franciscos 
+, Zeferino 
-, Jose Antonios
., . 
., . .
/, Celsos
17, Herbert Baltazar
`, Irving
```

I can filter the Subject_Name using like % but that's a lot of likes in the query. Is there a better way to pull those records from a large table?

Comment: What does the schema of table Subject_Name look like? Are you planning on doing something else after you identify these people?

Comment: Yes - Change those to correct names.

Comment: Be wary of just up and changing the names.  You'd be better off flagging them somehow, and requiring that the users provide you with a (validated) replacement.  For instance, I think I've seen the names of South African Bushmen rendered into english with the inclusion of a bang (`!`).

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to easily find non-alpha characters using a `LIKE` statement:

---

EDIT:

I thought `Subject_Name` was your table... but I guess it's your column.  Is both the first name and last name stored in that column, separated by a comma?  In that case, we'd need to add the comma to the allowed characters...  I'd also suggest splitting that one column into two.

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE Subject_Name LIKE '%[^ a-zA-Z,]%'
```

Comment: +1 You would also want to include space in there. I would delete my similar but later answer but am blocked from doing so as I have already deleted 5 old answers today.

Comment: Hi Michael, The Subject_Name is a column (format is Last name, First name). I tried to apply (Subject_Name like '%[^ a-zA-Z]%' OR Subject_name LIKE '%[^ a-zA-Z]%') and it still returns every record instead of what i was looking for. Did I miss something?

Comment: @X-Zero - That is why both answers include it as valid. The queries are looking for rows where the column value has a character **not** in the set delimited in square brackets.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Yeah, I realized that afterwards.  My regex is still a little iffy (I haven't had much chance to practice yet).

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
where Subject_Name LIKE '%[^a-Z ]%'  collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried as follow - SUBJECT_NAME LIKE '%[^a-Z ]%' and the result still returns every record. Did I miss somthing? Thanks

Comment: `SELECT name FROM master..spt_values where name LIKE '%[^a-Z ]%'  collate Latin1_General_CS_AI` works fine for me. Do all of your records have a non alpha character?

Comment: yes such as mentioned at the ogrinal question above. I am using MS SQL Sever 2000/2005/2008 version though.

Comment: @HungCaptain - You are not explaining this very well. Your original question says you are looking for records with special characters now you say "yes" all of your records have a non alpha character!?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it well. I should have stated that i was looking for records with special characters like in the original question. So, when applied the LIKE syntax, the query returns ALL records instead of ONLY records with special characters.

Comment: @HungCaptain - Which means that **all** of the records must contain a character other than alphabetical or a space. What character is it as that will presumably need to be added in to the list of "non special" characters. Is it the comma?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5138/discussion-between-hung-captain-and-martin-smith)

Comment: @HungCaptain - Any answer to the above?

Comment: @Martin, I am still trying to working on it. Will let you know

Comment: @HungCaptain -You can use `SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(Subject_Name,PATINDEX('%[^a-Z ]%',Subject_Name),1)) FROM YourTable where Subject_Name LIKE '%[^a-Z ]%'  collate Latin1_General_CI_AI` to get the ASCII code in case it is an unprintable character like tab or something.

Comment: Hi Martin, Hope all is well. Basically I want to pull the people where their names contain characters like *, +, /, ..., -, number, "'", [,. .,.. Thanks